# How to convert unicode to html entities in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, html-entities

I have a string like '\u00bd tsp crushed chillies, to taste' where '\u00bd' is the Unicode of vulgar fraction 1/2. I want to convert this to html entities like  `&#189;` (decimal) or `&#xbd;` (hex)

Comment: &#x1234; where 1234 are the unicode code points. Now you should look what it the unicode code for 1/2

Comment: It was there all the time. Sorry for my ignorance and thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated.